# Button.isSelected() does not return true

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a JFrame with 3 buttons, 3 checkboxes, and 3 radio buttons.
I'm having a problem with a function that is excecuted when 1 of the 3 buttons is pressed.
This is the function:

```
private void setCenterColors() {

    if(redB.isSelected()) {
        center.setBackground(Color.RED);
    } else if (greenB.isSelected()) {
        center.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (blueB.isSelected()){
        center.setBackground(Color.BLUE);   
    }
    System.out.println(center.getBackground());
}
```

redB, greenB, and blueB are all JButtons.

The event handler for the buttons is:

```
class ChoiceListenerButton implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            setCenterColors();
            repaint();
        }
    }

    listenerButton = new ChoiceListenerButton();
```

When i excecute the program and press the buttons, all of them returns false, when one of them should return true. What should i do to see which button is pressed? Any help is appreciated, if you need full code, please ask and i will replay as soon as is see the notification. Thank you.

Comment: A button has no isSelected () method! (in the title)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
class ChoiceListenerButton implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        setCenterColors(event);
        repaint();
    }

    private void setCenterColors(ActionEvent event) {
        if(event.getSource() == redB) {
            center.setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else if (event.getSource() == greenB) {
            center.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        } else if (event.getSource() == blueB){
            center.setBackground(Color.BLUE);   
        }
        System.out.println(center.getBackground());
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you have added `listenerButton` to buttons e.g. `redB.addActionListener(listenerButton)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Avind Kumar Avinash, I also had to change setCenterColors() to setCenterColros(event) but otherwise, that did the trick. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, that's obvious :). I missed it while typing. I've updated it now in my answer. Wish you success!

Comment: Sorry for not accepting sooner, was adding the finishing touches of my code. Thank you and is wish you success as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong doing it the way you are.  But you might find this useful in the future.

Since the `actionListener` is a `Functional Interface` you can use a lambda to specify the actionListener.  In your case an example would be:

```
        JButton red = new JButton("Set Red");
        red.addActionListener((ae) -> {
            panel.setBackground(Color.red);
            panel.repaint();
        });
```

For more complicated listeners, you can create a `private inner class` and pass the necessary information via the constructor.  Since it is an inner class, it has access to the instance field `panel` defined in the outer, containing class.

```
      private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        private Color color;

        public ButtonListener(Color color) {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            panel.setBackground(color);
            panel.repaint();
        }
      }
```

You would use it as follows:

```
       button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener(Color.red));
```

The idea is that you can use multiple action listeners to handle different siutations  or requirements.  In this case to set the appropriate color.